# Set singlequotes Coc-prettier in neovim

Tags: prettier, neovim

Im new using neovim and Coc-prettier. I would like to know how I can configure it so that single quotes are placed when formatting the document. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In coc-settings.json you can set prettier with:

```
{
    "prettier.singleQuote":true
}
```